# UI Date Picker not Displaying in Label

Tags: ios, objective-c, uidatepicker

When I go to a viewcontroller in my app, I have two date pickers. Both of which have labels, and if either one is moved they update accordingly.

The start date is set to automatically be today's date. While it saves to Core Data just fine it doesn't display in the label unless I change it to a different day.

Basically when I load that screen the label should have today's date, and change if I change it in the date picker.

I figure it's something simple overlooking, but I can't figure out what it is, any help would be appreciated.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    svos = self.scrollView.contentOffset;

    [self.startDate addTarget:self action:@selector(datePickerChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [self.endDate addTarget:self action:@selector(datePickerChanged1:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

    AppDelegate* appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    if(!appDelegate.dateProductionDroneStartDate)
        [self.startDate setDate:[NSDate date]];

    else
    {
        [self.startDate setDate:appDelegate.dateProductionDroneStartDate];
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-yyyy "];
        NSString *strDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:self.startDate.date];
        self.productionDroneStartDate.text = strDate;
    }

    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
    NSDateComponents *components = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [components setDay:1];
    NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSDate *newDate2 = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:components toDate:now options:0];

    if(!appDelegate.dateProductionDroneEndDate)
        [self.endDate setDate:newDate2];
    else
    {
        [self.endDate setDate:appDelegate.dateProductionDroneEndDate];
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-yyyy "];
        NSString *strDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:self.endDate.date];
        self.productionDroneEndDate.text = strDate;
    }

    self.txtProductionName.text = appDelegate.strProductionName;
    self.txtProductionScene.text = appDelegate.strProductionScene;
    self.txtProductionReel.text = appDelegate.strProductionReel;

    self.txtProductionName.delegate = self;
    self.txtProductionReel.delegate = self;
    self.txtProductionScene.delegate = self;
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                   initWithTarget:self
                                   action:@selector(dismissKeyboard)];

    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SO far what I got from ur question and code, simple mistake is as below :-

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
 [super viewDidLoad];
 ....
 NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-yyyy "];
 NSString *strDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:self.startDate.date];
 AppDelegate* appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
 if(!appDelegate.dateProductionDroneStartDate)   //As initially this will be true and current date will be set.
    [self.startDate setDate:[NSDate date]];
     //So as you set the current date in self.startDate but not in label.
     //Added below line for setting your label
 else
 {
    [self.startDate setDate:appDelegate.dateProductionDroneStartDate];
 }
 self.productionDroneStartDate.text = strDate;
 ......
}
```

This should get you working further.

Comment: Thanks for your help! So trying that I get an error in line     self = [super initWithNibName:0=nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
 saying expression is not assignable. Another one else that says expected expression,     NSDate *newDate2 = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:components toDate:now options:0];says incompatible pointer type. Is this because the NSDate formatter is now declared twice?

Comment: @user3856938 I have edited the post...! also where is [super initWith..] getting called. This changes have no connection with them!

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you just set the label with todays date at start without even touching the Picker. Then when the picker is moved as you suggest the label will be updated as expected.